# Cardinality of stabilizer in $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}_7)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $v$ be a non-zero vector in $\mathbb{Z}_7^2$ (up to scaling), and let P be the stabilizer of $v$ (up to scaling) in the Projective special linear group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}_7)$. Find the Cardinality of P.

Please help, I am not sure how to do this. All I have thought of just try to use the basic technique, 
$\begin{bmatrix}
   a & b \\
   c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
   v_1 \\
   v_2
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
   v_1 \\
   v_2
\end{bmatrix}$ 
and then try to find $a,b,c,d$, but it didn't got any good result.

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Take $v = [1,0]^t$. Then you might have better luck figuring out the entries of an element of $P$.

Comment: @peterag but I thought $v$ suppose to be fixed but arbitrary? Can I just pick $v=[0,1]^t$?

Comment: The point is that any other $v$ is of the form $g [1,0]^t$, so the stabilizer of $v$ is $g P g^{-1}$, where $P$ is the stabilizer of $[0,1]^t$.

Comment: Show that all ($(7^2-1)/(7-1)=8$) nonzero vectors lie in one orbit, so it does not matter which vector you stabilize.

Comment: so does it meant $a=1,c=0$? and $7$ choices for $b$, $6$ choices for $d$? so the cardinality of $P$ is 42?

Comment: @user138017: You're pretty close, but with your choices of $b$ and $d$ you'll get some matrices with a non-square determinant - those don't lie in $PSL(2, \mathbb{Z}_7)$.